# How can I set the legend text color when not selected in echarts?

Tags: javascript, echarts, apache-echarts

I'm trying to change the color of the legend text when a serie is unselected/not shown in echarts.

Using the `legend.textStyle.color` option, I am able to change the text color but only when the serie is shown.

However I can't seem to find a similar option for when the serie is not shown.

For example the settings:

```
legend: {
  top: '10%',
    textStyle: {
      color: 'red'
  }
}
```

results in the following (with series `medium` and `high` not selected)
[image]

But I'd like `medium` and `high` shown in a darker color

Am I missing it or is it just not there?

I've tried setting the color to an array (`color: ['red', 'blue']`) but that didn't work.

Comment: I created a [feature request](https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/16360) for this

Answer (score 1):

you can use  inactiveColor:"red",
something like below

```
legend: {
    data: [{name: 'Email',
    inactiveColor:"red",
    textStyle:{
       color:'green'
    },
    itemStyle: {
      //color: ['red', 'green'],
      color: '#ccc',
      borderType: [50, 10],
    }}, 'Union Ads', 'Video Ads', 'Direct', 'Search Engine']
  },
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the anwser but that will only modify the color of the icon in the legend.
What I'm after is changing the color of the text itself (the textStyle part of the configuration).
Unfortunately inactiveColor is not part of the textStyle config.